# Create SecKey with Data result nil

Tags: swift, security

I have publicKey, but i can't create SecKey, calling `SecKeyCreateWithData` returns `nil`

```
let base64PubKey = "MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEe0A0PYKX1LDjiJwpdPwRxlfcZL9vKQrp+CmT0xygyTWMjVkoRnY7bhfnP4eAyjaKNv675UsKrK+gXWjre3bYRg=="

let privData1 = NSData(base64Encoded: base64PubKey)

let privRaw1 = privData1?.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
let CFPrivData1 = CFDataCreate(nil, privRaw1!, privData1!.count)

let attributes123 = [kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom,
                kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
                kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String: 384
                ] as [CFString : Any]


let pubKey123 = SecKeyCreateWithData(CFPrivData1 as! CFData, attributes123 as CFDictionary, &error) // this is nil
```

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code as text, using proper code formatting - and not as a screenshot -, in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: Ok,  i change question

Comment: What format is this key in? SecKeyCreateWithData expects ANSI X9.63 for elliptic curve public keys. I expect the first byte to x04, but in your data it's 0x30. See SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation for documentation on the expected formats. What do you see in the returned `error`?